# Helium's API : Selection List options not able to select

Tags: python-3.x, playwright-python, helium

Learning Helium for automation;

I could not able to select List options either using Click or Hover and Click. Is it any solutions?

for an example;

https://bigcrewnow.in/product/iphone-5s-32gb/ - in the page have an Colors option and would be select "Silver" or any other option; i could not be selected...

```
from helium import *
from selenium.webdriver import FirefoxOptions
options = FirefoxOptions()
options.add_argument("--width=1920")
options.add_argument("--height=1080")


url = 'https://bigcrewnow.in/product/iphone-5s-32gb/'

session = HTMLSession()
response =  session.get(url)
browserx = start_firefox(url,headless=False)
press(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
click('Choose an Option')
# I could not able to select any options under Colors
browserx.quit();kill_browser()
```

Answer (score 0):

select(ComboBox("Choose an option"),"Silver") -  selected an option from list, here, they are specified as ComboBox.

```
from helium import *
start_firefox("https://bigcrewnow.in/product/iphone-5s-32gb/",headless=False)
select(ComboBox("Choose an option"),"Gold")
kill_browser()
```